# Вычисление квадратного корня на натуральных числах

Tags: алгоритм, численные-методы

Есть некая функция

[image]

где [image]

Возникла необходимость вычислять обратную функцию

[image]

Сейчас думаю над элегантным и не слишком медленным методом вычисления x(y). Какие у меня есть варианты?

Comment: Прошу прощения, поверил обещаниям, что поддерживается ввод разметки TeX. @Barmaley, переделал в глинянные таблички.

Comment: Ничего не понял - формулу то напиши...

Comment: @karmadro4, Это вопрос на форум [Математика](http://math.hashcode.ru/).

Comment: Блин, опять настал формулам капут.
@Павел Зайцев, лол, нет. Не пугайтесь, этот матан не так страшен :-)

Comment: @karmadro4, TeX-разметка поддерживается только на форуме "Математика".

Answer (score 5):

Стандартное рекуррентное соотношение не подойдет?

```
// x(n + 1) = 0.5*(x(n) + n / x(n))

scanf("%u", &test_number);

x_new = test_number;
x_old = 0;

while (x_old != x_new) {
    x_old = x_new;
    x_new = (x_new + test_number / x_new) >> 1;
}

printf("%u\n", x_new);
```

Comment: О, формула Герона! Как раз сейчас экспериментирую с ней. Кстати, сходится гораздо быстрее если покормить не нулем, а грубой оценкой.

Answer (score 4):

Если правильно понял насчет натуральных чисел, то вот для целых 32-бит.

```
unsigned int 
sqrt32(unsigned long n)  
{  
    unsigned int c = 0x8000;  
    unsigned int g = 0x8000;

    for(;;) {  
        if(g*g > n)  
            g ^= c;  
        c >>= 1;  
        if(c == 0)  
            return g;  
        g |= c;  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Интересный подход, хотя я мало чего понял :-) А ограничение натуральными числами позволяет не волноваться о том, существует ли обратная функция или нет.

Comment: Алгоритм не мой, из интернета. Насколько понимаю программная модель кусочка железяки. По крайней мере так сказал человек, который когда-то разрабатывал железо.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую поиграться с ним и обобщить для разных разрядностей.

Comment: Спасибо, скопировал себе.

Answer (score 0):

Разложить в ряд Тейлора